# How do I eliminate duplicates from a CSV file using PHP's fgetcsv?

Tags: php, fopen, fgetcsv, fclose

I am parsing a CSV file using fgetcsv, specifically using $line_of_text. I want to echo all the cities that have a shared country, but I want to eliminate city duplicates so that if, for example, Paris occurred 200 times it would only be echoed once, along a single echo for the other distinct cities of France regardless of their number of instances.

My hunch is that I need to store the city values in an array and then use array_unique to remove duplicates, but unfortunately this is beyond my current php abilities. Any help deeply appreciated, I've tried everything in my powers!

```
<?php
  $display = 100;
  $counter = 1;
  $country = $_GET['country'];
  echo "<ol>";
  $file_handle = fopen("csv/file.csv", "r");
  while (($line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ",")) !== false) {
      if ($line_of_text[13] == $country) {
          echo "<li>City:" . $line_of_text[15]) . "</li>";

          $counter++;
          if ($counter == $display) {
              break;
              echo "</ol>";
          }
      }
  }
  fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just working from memory, try something like

```
<?php
  $display = 100;
  $counter = 1;
  $country = $_GET['country'];
  $storedcountries = array();//Store countries that have already been read
  echo "<ol>";
  $file_handle = fopen("csv/file.csv", "r");
  while (($line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024, ",")) !== false) {
      if ($line_of_text[13] == $country && !in_array($storedcountries, $line_of_text[13]) {//Make sure the country is not already stored in the $storedcountries array
          echo "<li>City:" . $line_of_text[15]) . "</li>";

          $counter++;
          if ($counter == $display) {
              break;
              echo "</ol>";
          }
          $storedcountries[] = $line_of_text[15];
      }
  }
  fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Comment: Cheers, but I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 102

Comment: Sorry, to clarity, the parse error is occuring on this line:
if ($line_of_text[13] == $country && !in_array($storedcountries, $line_of_text[13]) {

Comment: Just had the Parameters around the wrong way: ($line_of_text[13], $storedcountries). Worked perfect once I'd fixed it - legend!

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code a bit:

```
// read in file
$csv = array_map("str_getcsv", file("csv/file.csv"));
$cities = array();

// loop for countries
foreach ($csv as $line) {
    if ($line[13] == $country) {
        $cities[] = $line[15];    // append to new array
    }
}

// unique cities
$cities = array_unique($cities);
$cities = array_slice($cities, 0, 100);   // max 100

// output
foreach ($cities as $name) { print "<li>City: $name</li>"; }
```

You should try to keep processing logic and output separated like this.