# How to check csv file has duplicate value before inserting to the table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I' have problem csv on upload, First I want to check the duplicate data or column or row before i enter it into the database. I have 2 columns/row, I want to check all the data on the two columns or row before it inserted it into the table.

Note: If duplicates found in all two columns or row it will throw and error or echo the duplicate value, And it will not continue to the insert function.

```
$stored = [];
$handle2 = fopen($_FILES["charge_file"]["tmp_name"],"r");
while(($data1 = fgetcsv($handle2,1000,",")) !==false){

    $charge_emp = trim($data1[0]);
    $charge_amount = trim($data1[2]);



    // this is the function on checking the duplicates
    if (in_array($data1[0], $stored)) { continue;}
    $stored[] = $data1[0];

    showDups($stored);


    // this is my insert function
    charges_group_entry($charge_emp,$charge_amount);

}

fclose($handle);

function showDups($array)
{
    $array_temp = array();

    foreach($array as $val)
    {
        if (!in_array($val, $array_temp))
        {
        $array_temp[] = $val;
        }
        else
        {
        echo 'duplicate = ' . $val . '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code or what trouble do you have? Please tell us more about desired result.

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931404/how-do-i-eliminate-duplicates-from-a-csv-file-using-phps-fgetcsv

Comment: @marv255 it updated the data. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "duplicates data found on 2 columns" so here's two solutions in one :

```
$stored_emp = [];
$stored_amount = [];
$stored_pair = [];
$global_duplicate=false;
$handle2 = fopen($_FILES["charge_file"]["tmp_name"],"r");
while(($data1 = fgetcsv($handle2,1000,",")) !==false){

    $charge_emp = trim($data1[0]);
    $charge_amount = trim($data1[2]);
    $pair = $charge_emp.' '.$charge_amount;

    // this is the code for checking the duplicates separately
    $duplicate=false;
    if (in_array($charge_emp, $stored_emp)) {
      echo 'duplicate emp = ' . $charge_emp . '<br />';
      $duplicate=true;
    }
    if (in_array($charge_amount, $stored_amount)) {
      echo 'duplicate amount = ' . $charge_amount . '<br />';
      $duplicate=true;
    }
    if($duplicate){
      $global_duplicate=true;
      continue;
    }
    $stored_emp[] = $charge_emp;
    $stored_amount[] = $charge_amount;

    //use this instead if you want to check pair duplicates
    if (in_array($pair, $stored_pair)) {
      echo 'duplicate pair = ' . $pair . '<br />';
      $global_duplicate=true;
      continue;
    }
    $stored_pair[] = $pair;
}
//only insert values if no duplicates found
if(!$global_duplicate){
  foreach($stored_emp as $nrow=>$emp){
    charges_group_entry($emp,$stored_amount[$nrow]);
  }
}

fclose($handle);
```

In any cases `showDups` wasn't needed (nor used) since you already filtered `$stored`.

Comment: if duplicates found in all two columns it will throw and error or echo the duplicate value, And it will not continue to the insert function.

Comment: I edited my answer to prevent insert if a duplicate was found, is it better ?

Comment: Its not what I expected output, but this might help. I would do the other trick though its very helpful, Thanks man.